# HTML: text input is not being submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have an HTML form with many fields, including a text field, that is,

```
<input name="my_field" type="text"></input>
```

Now, this text field is being changed by tons of JavaScript, jQuery and CSS code. The result of all this interaction is that when the form is submitted, this particular text field simply gets ignored (it is like that field was not there). I am not saying it get submitted with empy text, it simply doesn't appear in the list of fields submitted...

Because there are tons of code affecting this particular text field, I don't know what is causing this weird behavior. So I was wondering if someone could tell me what kind of HTML attribute (or JavaScript code, or jQuery code, or ...) could result in a text field being ignored.

At the end of all this interaction, I get the following HTML code (retrieved using the "Inspect Element" from Chrome):

```
<input id="id_my_field" maxlength="200" name="my_field" type="text" class="tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" dir="auto" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; background-color: transparent;" data-original-title="" title=""></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `name` attribute, like this:

```
<input name="myField" type="text"></input>
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that the name attribute is being set. Question edited.

Comment: I just posted something that might help.

Comment: Firebag use to view the post data sent on server

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `name` attribute to the input:

```
<input type="text" name="myinput" />
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that the name attribute is being set. Question edited.